# Issue on removing connection while closing Application

Tags: c#, .net, rabbitmq, amqp

I am using .NET RabbitMQ Client library. I want to develop a messaging system. For this, I have implemented all necessary methods of RabbitMQ. Moreover I have to develop a `dispose()` for removing connection from RabbitMQ as connections are not removed automatically. I am calling this method in `FormClosing()` event so this method will be triggered when user closes the application by clicking on close button and by the logic connection will be removed. Up to this, all code is working perfectly.

The problem is, calling a `dispose()` to remove connections explicitly is bad practice so i don’t want to use `dispose()`. I'm not able to remove any
connection at the time of closing the application without triggering
`dispose()`.  Connection remains in RabbitMQ.

How can I remove these connections from RabbitMQ without calling
`dispose()` explicitly?

Comment: What makes you think that *"Calling a dispose() to remove connections explicitly is bad practice"*? If you don't use a `using` with your disposable RabbitMQ connection, just call dispose manually on app closing.

Comment: @oleksii: Thanks for your reply. What I am doing is, I am creating Library for my own use, which will extend existing RabbitMQ .NET Library. I will use this library for further development of messaging System. I have added few methods in Library and have not used _using_ because the flow of the library is transferring data from one `cs` file to another. **What makes you think that** _"Calling a `dispose()` to remove connections explicitly is bad practice_"**?**. I can not ask developer to call this `dispose()` to close the connection.

Comment: You can probably add an interface that has `Open` and `Close` methods. It will then be clear to the user of your library of how to use it. Inside the close method you can call `Dispose`.

Comment: "I can not ask developer to call this `dispose()` to close the connection." Yes, you can. You say you're developing a library for this. Part of library design is deciding which methods do which things. It's reasonable to say "If you want to close a connection call `TheConnectionClass.Dispose()`."